# Assigning a listeof alphabet array to a list of number array

Tags: arrays, list, python-3.x

I am a newbie and my question is simple. I have two lists of arrays as follows:

```
Grade = ["A","A-","B+","B","B-","C+","C","C-","D","F"]
GPA = [4,3.75,3.25,3,2.75,2.25,2,1.75,1,0]
```

How do I assign A = 4, A- = 3.75 and so on from the list.

Please help!!

Comment: Use the eval python command.

Comment: e.g. A- and B+ are not valid variable names.

Comment: @Michel Keijzers NEVER use eval. Edit `locals`, `globals`, whatever, but NOT eval.

Comment: @BasicWolf: for that matter, you shouldn't modify `locals()` -- changing it doesn't have the effects you'd think it would.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use the `zip` function:

```
grade_gpa = zip(Grade, GPA)
for pair in grade_gpa:
    print(pair)
>>>
('A', 4)
('A-', 3.75)
('B+', 3.25)
('B', 3)
('B-', 2.75)
('C+', 2.25)
('C', 2)
('C-', 1.75)
('D', 1)
('F', 0)
```

Moreover you can construct a dictionary out of the zip object:

```
grade_gpa_dict = dict(grade_gpa)
print(grade_gpa_dict['A'])
>>> 4
```

Comment: the first part is ok.

but when I run:
grade_gpa_dict = dict(grade_gpa)
print(grade_gpa_dict['A'])

it gives me key errors!

Comment: @user2042721: the `zip` object `grade_gpa` can only be iterated over once in Python 3, so if you make a dict from it after the print loop there's nothing left.  Simply use `grade_gpa_dict = dict(zip(Grade, GPA))`.

Answer (score -1):

Using built-in map/reduce:

```
import functools

a = map(lambda x,y : {x:y}, Grade, GPA)
b = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: dict(x.items() + y.items()), a)

b["A"] => 4
```

Comment: How is this better than `dict(zip(Grade, GPA))`?

Comment: Indeed I did not see the "3.x" in the question tag, my bad. And it's not "better" than your answer, just different ^^ BTW I've edited my answer with the name of the package where they pushed reduce.

Comment: indeed, your answer is different, what I'm trying to say that doesn't it look overly complicated? For example, in `map()` you create a `dict` object per every pair. Also `x.items() + y.items()` would not work in Py3 because `dict.items()` is an iterator, (should convert it to a list). Overall - you have to write 3 lines of code (including the `import`) instead of a single and simple one. The bottom line is that your code works fine, but it has neither performance nor readability advantage. See the first three statements of the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) :)